# How to create an empty tuple of specific type in Julia?

Tags: struct, tuples, julia

How do I initialize a mutable struct with an empty tuple of specific type?

e.g. given

```
mutable struct myStruct
    info::Tuple{Int, Int}
end
```

How would I create a variable `x = myStruct(info = ())`

Where `x.info` is an empty tuple and `typeof(x.info) = Tuple{Int, Int}`

Comment: "x is an empty tuple of type `Tuple{myStruct, myStruct}`" doesn't really make sense because the very meaning of that type definition is that the tuple contains two elements, each a `myStruct`- so, not empty. Can you explain what you need this for, so we can look for alternate ways to achieve your goal?

Comment: i have edited the question to hopefully make it clearer

Comment: If you really need a structure field that may contain either 0 or 2 integers, you may as well use a vector of Int. Tuples are only more efficient than vectors when the compiler can make useful assumptions about their fixed memory footprint. In many other situations, where that memory footprint varies, they may waste allocations.

Comment: I would define `info` as an `Union{Nothing,Tuple{Int,Int}}` and initialize myStruct with `myStruct{nothing`}. In this way you can always distinguish an initialised struct from one that happens to have zeros as values. By the way, in Julia it is common to start struct names with capital letters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot create an empty tuple of type `Tuple{Int,Int}`. By definition, a `Tuple{Int, Int}` has a length of 2 and is thus not empty.

Compare this to an empty `Array{Int}` which can have a length of 0 and is thus empty:

```
julia> empty_array = Int[]
Int64[]

julia> isempty(empty_array)
true

julia> length(empty_array)
0
```

The long answer is it depends what you mean by "empty". Perhaps you mean something that you did not have to initialize. We can partly investigate this using a `Ref`. In this case the values will be whatever is resident in memory. Overall, I'm not sure what advantage this would have over just initializing the tuple as `(0,0)`.

```
julia> r = Ref{Tuple{Int,Int}}()
Base.RefValue{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}((2, 139735268818544))

julia> r = Ref{Tuple{Int,Int}}()
Base.RefValue{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}((139735268745904, 139735268746800))

julia> isempty(r[])
false
```

It is not clear to me overall why you want an empty tuple other than as a default initial value for a default `myStruct` constructor.

For a default constructor, I recommend using `(0,0)` as the initial value:

```
julia> mutable struct myStruct
           info::Tuple{Int, Int}
       end

julia> myStruct() = myStruct((0,0))
myStruct

julia> myStruct()
myStruct((0, 0))
```

My last guess at why you might want an "empty" tuple is to avoid allocations.  Creating a `myStruct` instance results in a 32 byte allocation. To avoid allocations, the best course of action would be to make the struct immutable. Doing so comes with a multitude of advantages such as simplified memory layout involving less pointer indirection. It also allows the compiler to make simplifying assumptions resulting in faster code.

```
julia> @time myStruct();
  0.000001 seconds (1 allocation: 32 bytes)

julia> struct NonAllocatingStruct
           info::Tuple{Int, Int}
       end

julia> NonAllocatingStruct() = NonAllocatingStruct((0,0))
NonAllocatingStruct

julia> @time NonAllocatingStruct()
  0.000002 seconds
NonAllocatingStruct((0, 0))
```